# MLlib MatrixFactorizationModel recommendProducts(user, num) returns training data product items also

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering, matrix-factorization

I have created an ALS model using Spark MLib:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel

// Build the recommendation model using ALS
val rank = 10
val numIterations = 10
val model = ALS.train(trainingGrid, rank, numIterations)
```

Structure of my training grid is like this:

```
+-----------+----------+---------+--------+---------+
|.  Bought|cidIndex|productIndex|
+-----------+----------+---------+--------+---------+
|     true|    38.0| 113959.0|
|    false|    38.0| 193806.0|
|     true|    38.0| 260716.0|
|     true|    38.0|   7038.0|
|    false|   107.0|  93949.0|
|    false|    38.0|  13484.0|
|    false|    38.0|  59290.0|
|    false|    38.0|  76696.0|
|    false|   107.0|  71311.0|
|     true|    38.0|  92553.0|
+-----------+----------+---------+--------+---------+
```

It has around 20K records like this.

After the training I am calling,

```
val products = model.recommendProducts(38,5)
```

This returns me below items:

```
Rating(38,260716,0.9800308437967447)
Rating(38,219601,0.9800308437967447)
Rating(38,61616,0.9800308437967447)
Rating(38,113959,0.9800308437967447)
Rating(38,92553,0.9800308437967447)
```

Problem is out of these 5 items 3 items are already there in training data. 
260716, 113959 and 92553.

When I call recommend items to ALS, all I expected was it recommends product which user hasn't already bought. But I am surprised to see why the model returns data which is already present in training data.

Can someone please help me how to avoid training data itself getting predicted?

Comment: Not sure if it matters but did you use the `Rating` object for the data when training (see here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html)?

Comment: Also, see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938478/get-wrong-recommendation-with-als-recommendation

Comment: Yes I used import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating object